# Finding a proposal distribution in acceptance-rejection method

Tags: mathematical-statistics, monte-carlo, accept-reject

I'm learning the Acceptance-Rejection method but I am having a hard time finding a g(x) except using uniform distribution to simulate the f(x).
[image]

How could we find a g(x) that has a simple pdf and is appropriate to use?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use kernel density estimation (KDE) to get a smoothed function of the histogram of the data (pdf), and then employ the acceptance/rejection method.  You could also fit a cubic spline on the histogram bin values to get an approximation of the pdf function.